# can I get function from class pointer by casting

Tags: c++

I have this class
and I am trying to extract x1 function from pointer of my class pointer

```
class myclass
{
public:
myclass();
~myclass();
int x = 0;
int x1();
private:



};

int myclass::x1() 
{
return 100;
}
```

like this

```
myclass* ptr = new myclass[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
ptr[i].x = i*11;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
 std::cout << ((ptr + i)->x) << std::endl;
 void *v = (void *)((ptr + i)->x);
 typedef int (*fptr)()=//what I need to do to v to get x1 function and call it; 
    
}
```

can I do this. Is this allowed in C++. I am using VS2019

Comment: If you _could_ get an `int(*)()` for a member function, and you called it (with no arguments), what would `this->x` be during the call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use ***pointer to member functions***. The syntax is like:

```cpp
int (myclass::*myFuncPtr)() = &myclass::x1;
// call it by object 
(object.*myFuncPtr)();
// or by the pointer of the object
(objectPtr->*myFuncPtr)();
```

A more modern way is:

```cpp
using MyFuncPtr = decltype(&myclass::x1);
MyFuncPtr myFuncPtr = &myclass::x1;
// both by object
std::invoke(myFuncPtr, object);
// and by pointer is correct
std::invoke(myFuncPtr, objectPtr);
```

Notice that you must provide an object for `this` in the member function. Only static member functions can be directly called without being bound to an object.

You may refer to my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74673390/15582103) to know more about it.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, you cannot directly access member functions through a pointer to a member variable. To access and call the x1 function of your class, you need to have a pointer to an instance of myclass, not just a pointer to a member variable.

```
myclass* ptr = new myclass[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    ptr[i].x = i * 11;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    std::cout << ((ptr + i)->x) << std::endl;
    myclass* instance = ptr + i; // Get the pointer to the current instance

    int result = instance->x1(); // Call the x1 function

    std::cout << "x1 result: " << result << std::endl;
}

delete[] ptr; // Delete the allocated memory
```

Comment: can u please tell what version of C++ does VS2019 uses

Comment: Visual Studio 2019 supports multiple versions of C++. The specific version depends on the compiler version and the project settings. To determine the exact version, you can check the project settings, right-click on the project in the Solution Explorer and select "Properties" from the context menu than "Configuration Properties" -> "General" look for the "C++ Language Standard" or "C++ Language Standard" option.